# PLAX parallaxing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I'm trying to get 2 transparent images to parallax over a static background contained within the header using the [PLAX jQuery plugin](http://cameronmcefee.com/plax/) by Cameron McEfee. It looks something like this:

Head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plax.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#anotherWrapperForSomeReason img').plaxify()
$.plax.enable()
})
</script>
```

Body

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="superfluousWrapper">
            <div id="anotherWrapperForSomeReason">
                    <div id="crosses">
                    <img id="crosses1" src="images/crossesover1.png" data-xrange="40" data-yrange="40" data-invert="false">
                    <img id="crosses2" src="images/crossesover2.png" data-xrange="20" data-yrange="20" data-invert="false">
                    <img id="stars1" src="images/starsover1.png" data-xrange="10" data-yrange="10" data-invert="true">
                    </div>                
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    }
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.superfluousWrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
#anotherWrapperForSomeReason {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: url(images/aboutheader.png) center center no-repeat;
    }
#crosses {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 496px;
    overflow: hidden;
        }
#crosses1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    }
#crosses2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    }
#stars1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    }
```

I have the the plax and jQuery js linked in my `<head>` and followed [the directions](https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax/blob/master/readme.md) to the letter, still nothing is responding to the code.  Someone help me figure out what I'm missing/doing wrong please.

***edited/reformat***

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: @vals aside from a few unrelated jQuery warnings, not a one

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the jquery library version  like jquery1.6.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plax.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#crosses1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
$('#crosses2').plaxify({"xRange":20,"yRange":20,"invert":true})
$.plax.enable({ "activityTarget": $('.container')})
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    }
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.superfluousWrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
.anotherWrapperForSomeReason {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: url(images/aboutheader.png) center center no-repeat;
    }
#crosses {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 496px;
    overflow: hidden;
        }
#crosses1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    }
#crosses2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="superfluousWrapper">
            <div class="anotherWrapperForSomeReason">
                    <div id="crosses">
                    <img id="crosses1" src="crossover-1.png">
                    <img id="crosses2" src="crossover-2.png">
                    </div>                
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: yeah I have the `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` added

I also have a downloaded copy linked locally which is v1.10.1 `<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>`

Should I only have one and not the other?

Comment: Hi, 
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#crosses1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
$('#crosses2').plaxify({"xRange":20,"yRange":20,"invert":true})
$.plax.enable({ "activityTarget": $('.container')})
});
</script>

Comment: Add $(document).ready(function() { }); between of your script. Its work fine to me

Comment: Yeah I did realize that and added it but it didn't make a difference to me, in chrome or in FF.

I have a simplified grouped version like the readme recommended:
 `$(document).ready(function () {
$('.anotherWrapperForSomeReason img').plaxify()
$.plax.enable()
})`

The xrange and yrange are defined inline with the data attribute

Comment: still nothing, using FF's error console, the only errors I'm getting are related to my adblock extension. Nothing wrong with the syntax or code.

Comment: Got it, I just had to rename my elements, there was some kind of conflict using them between other pages even though the css was still technically correct.

Comment: Could you try jQuery.noConflict()? $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($)

Comment: I was trying to reuse the same containing elements from a different page but a unique nested element, like: `<div class="container1"><div class="container2"><div id="uniqueElement"></div>/div></div>` and `<div class="container1"><div class="container2"><div id="anotherUniqueElement"></div>/div></div>` and for some reason it didn't like that.  I changed the names of the second set of container classes and it worked fine.